# Is there a website that lets you shop for hotels with taxes and fees included in search results?

Tags: online-resources, bookings, hotels, price, accommodation-search-engines

Every time I book a hotel online, the price increases by 25% in "taxes and fees" at checkout, compared to the price featured in search results.  This does not occur when booking flights (I actually think there's a regulation against it for flights).  Is there a website that lets you compare the ACTUAL price of hotels with taxes and fees included, and also lets you book?

Comment: I think this varies by country - maybe try booking with an EU-based website? (Customer facing sites in the EU have to display tax-inclusive pricing)

Comment: Yes, a country is needed. VTC as too broad.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With [Kayak](https://www.kayak.com), when looking at hotel search results, there is a dropdown under Price (circled in the screenshot below).  The default is "Nightly base price", which does not include taxes and fees, but you can also select "Nightly + local taxes & fees" or "Total stay + taxes & fees", which accomplishes what this question wants.

[image]

Comment: Tested and this actually works!