# Where can I compare airfares *including baggage fees*?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, online-resources, bookings, price

There are lots of places where I can compare flight fare costs, where the listed prices include all taxes and fees.

This capability is eroding due to practices like route-dependent carry-on bag fees that are very hard to locate in order to quantify.  I've had searches where I wind up finding a list of flight options, then spending a half an hour *per option* to try to quantify the baggage fees, and once you value that time you're not really saving anything by doing a price comparison.

I'd like to be able to enter into a search engine whether or not I plan to bring a carry-on and how many bags I plan to check, so that I can see the price of the ticket as I plan to take it, and not have to search for the modifiers every time.  Does this exist?

---

Related: [Is there a website that lets you shop for hotels with taxes and fees included in search results?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/80880/31076)